# adding database query in XLS

Tags: php, mysql, excel, xls

I have some difficulties getting the XLS function to add the query result in a xls file. 
I have a html and a php file who is doing the job. 
The query is working as it should, but i think the XLS function is not fetching the query result. I get "whitescreen" after pressing the button in the html file.

```
<div class="right" style="width:940px;">
          <a href="/statistics/orders/stats.xls" i18n:translate="">Download as .XLS</a>
        </div>
```

i want the query to be saved in an xls file that can be saved localy.
The php is looking like this:

```
<?PHP

    import( 'pages.admin' );

class AdminPortalStatistics extends AdminPage implements IView {
    protected $template = 'order.stats';


    public
    function Execute() {

        $kode = 'ST1';
        $from = '2017-06-20';
        $to = '2017-07-29';

        if ($_GET['from'] && $_GET['to']) {

            $from = $_GET['from'];
            $to = $_GET['to'];

            $query = "SELECT * from history_ordrer ho INNER JOIN history_cusomer hc ON ho.ordrenr = hc.ordrenr INNER JOIN history_mal hm ON ho.ordrenr = hm.ordrenr INNER JOIN histort_orderline hol ON ho.ordrenr = hol.ordrenr  INNER JOIN kunde k ON ho.uid = k.uid WHERE ho.kode = ? AND ho.time BETWEEN ? AND ? AND  ho.deleted is null order by ho.ordernr desc";

            $orders = DB::query($query, $kode, $from, $to) - > fetchAll(DB::FETCH_ASSOC);
            $this - > stats = $orders;

        }

        $this - > kode = $kode;
        $this - > from = $from;
        $this - > to = $to;
    }



         public function XLS(  ) {

         $this->Execute(    );

         $this->setTemplate( false );

         $oldreporting = error_reporting( 0 );

         require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

         // Creating a workbook
         $workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

         // sending HTTP headers

         $workbook->send('test.xls');

         // Creating a worksheet
         $worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet( 'Report' );

         // write the data
         $fields = array_merge( array( 'Period' ), $this->series );
         $worksheet->writeRow( $row++, 0, $fields );

         foreach( $this->values as $graph ) {
            $line = array_merge( array( $graph['label'] ), $graph['data'] );
            $worksheet->writeRow( $row++, 0, $line );
         }

         // Let's send the file
         $workbook->close();

         error_reporting( $oldreporting );

      }


    }
?>
```

Comment: With this code a white screen can be correct: Nothing is returned (ie: No `return something` at the end of your function

Comment: If you really wrote the following code,  you should know how to debug it

Comment: i've written the query the, but the xls (pear) i havent used before

Comment: still havent found out how to get the  public function XLS to "fetch" the query result.